# R change the colour of bar in a stacked barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

Here is a barplot that I constructed:

```
data<-read.table(text="Unsuit   lsuit   imp
164 124 480
115 28  31
55  165 9
",header=T)

barplot(as.matrix(data))
```

[image]

It is a stacked barplot, each bar has three sub-bar (bottom, middle and the top)(sorry for the use of wrong jargon)

What I want to do is:

1) give the bottom sub-bar in `Unsuit` (corresponding to the value 164), middle sub-bar in `lsuit`(28) and top sub-bar in `imp` (9) the same colour (brown)

2) middle sub-bar `Unsuit`(115), bottom sub-bar in `lsuit` and middle sub-bar in `imp` same colour (red)

3) top sub-bar in `Unsuit` (55), top sub-bar in 'lsuit`(165) and bottom sub-bar in`imp`(480) the same colour (green)

and then show the colour of sub-bar in a legend

Would really appreciate on advise how to do this in R. I do not want to change the order of the bar which is important for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to draw rectangles by hand. 
Here's a possible function (pretty generic, it takes a matrix of values and a matrix of corresponding colors) that should give your desired result :

```
# custom function
customBarPlot <- function(valueMatrix,colorMatrix,main=NULL){

  stopifnot(all(dim(valueMatrix) == dim(colorMatrix)))

  maxVal <- max(apply(valueMatrix,2,cumsum))

  # draw an empty plot  
  plot(0,type='n',xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,maxVal),main = main,xlab=NA,ylab=NA,axes=FALSE)

  nCols <- ncol(valueMatrix)

  space <- 0.03 # 3% of the space between bars
  barWidth <- (1.0 - nCols * space + space) / nCols

  # add the rectangles
  for(col in 1:nCols){

    centerOfRect <- col * (space + barWidth) - barWidth / 2

    centers <- rep.int(centerOfRect,nCols)

    rect(xleft=centers - barWidth / 2,
         xright=centers + barWidth / 2,
         ybottom=c(0,head(cumsum(valueMatrix[,col]),-1)),
         ytop=cumsum(valueMatrix[,col]),
         col=colorMatrix[,col])
  }

  # add axis
  axis(1,at=1:nCols * (space + barWidth) - barWidth / 2, labels=colnames(valueMatrix),tick=FALSE) 
  axis(2)

  invisible()
}


# let's call the function

data<-read.table(text="Unsuit   lsuit   imp
164 124 480
115 28  31
55  165 9
",header=T)

customBarPlot(valueMatrix=as.matrix(data),
              colorMatrix=rbind(c('Brown','Red','Green'),
                                c('Red','Brown','Red'),
                                c('Green','Green','Brown')))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Edited: sorry, I copied my trial&error code instead of the correct version